# how to disable precompile MVC cshml page ASP.NET Core 5.0

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-5.0

I want to avoid precompile of my MVC .cshtml files

During publishing ASP.NET Core 5.0 website (not Razor Views) it is pre-compile my MVC .cshtml views.

Instead of dll, I want normal .cshml file

I have tried following ways but it is not working.

Modified project file

```
    <PropertyGroup>
      <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
      <PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>
      <MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>false</MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>
      <CopyRazorGenerateFilesToPublishDirectory>true</CopyRazorGenerateFilesToPublishDirectory>
    </PropertyGroup>
    
    <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation" Version="5.0.1" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Modified startup.cs html

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
}
```

Can anyone please help me to figure it out this problem?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why don't you want your views to be pre-compiled on publish? On-demand compilation really slows down the time it takes to serve the first page view, which might alienate your users.

Answer (score 2):

Tested the below in ASP.NET Core 6.

If you add

```
<RazorCompileOnPublish>false</RazorCompileOnPublish>
```

inside the property group tag of your csproj, then when you publish your web app it will create an additional Views Folder with your cshtml files.
However if you edit one of these cshtml files then the change won't reflect on your published website.

For it to reflect you have to add the nuget package to your project

```
 Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation
```

which will also install various other dependent packages

and allow you to add Runtime compilation in your Program.cs/Startup.cs

```
 builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
```

Doing the above has the disadvantage of adding additional language folders in your publish directory. You can prevent them from being added by addding

```
    <SatelliteResourceLanguages>en</SatelliteResourceLanguages>
```

inside the property group tag of your csproj

[Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-compilation?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio)

Answer (score 1):

According to [this Github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/16688), the `.csproj` flag is now called `<RazorCompileOnPublish>` for ASP.NET Core 3 and above:

> the property `MvcRazorCompileOnPublish` is supported for legacy purposes [...], but we recommend using `<RazorCompileOnPublish>false</RazorCompileOnPublish>` instead.

Comment: I made above changes but still views are compiles into dll

Comment: Thanks, this work. Tested in .net 6. I added `<RazorCompileOnPublish>false</RazorCompileOnPublish>` inside the PropertyGroup tag of the csproj and now a seperate Views folder with the cshtml get created on publish.

Answer (score 1):

just reference Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation in your .csproj

```
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation" Version="5.0.10" />
```

And add these two lines of code

```
  <CopyRazorGenerateFilesToPublishDirectory>true</CopyRazorGenerateFilesToPublishDirectory>
<GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
```

Eventually your cs file will look something like this :

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
<PropertyGroup>
 <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  <CopyRazorGenerateFilesToPublishDirectory>true</CopyRazorGenerateFilesToPublishDirectory>
 <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
</PropertyGroup>
 <ItemGroup>
 <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation" Version="5.0.10" />
 </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

and in your Startup File Add Service Like This

```
 services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
```

and After publishing it, you can see the views and pages folders in your files and edit them.

Comment: I made above changes but still views are compiles into dll

Comment: That doesn't matter. Do you see the views and pages  folders after publishing?

Comment: No I cannot view it